# Trying to avoid adding uncessary user_id field into rails db schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationships

So I have 3 models: Order, Item, and User.

```
User
has_many :items

Order
has_many :items

Item
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :order
```

My problem is: I want to also associate the User and Order models (like have an association:  Order :belongs_to :user, User has_many :orders).  I want to make a new column in the Order model that contains :user_id.  But is this incorrect, since an Item already has an association with a user?  Is there a fancy through relationship that can get me what I need, without adding an extra user_id field into the database?

I could technically say:

```
User 
has_many :orders, :through => :items

Order
has_many :users, :through => :items
```

But this feels like a hack to me.  In order to get the user associated with an order, I would have to say order.users.first (An order has_many :items, but all items will only have one user)

Also btw, I can not get rid of the Item's association with a user, as there is a period of time where an Item is created and not associated with an Order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to get yourself in trouble in the long run if you keep both kinds of associations.  I think you're better off setting things up correctly now and using a rake task to conform the old data to your new schema.

So set up `User -> Order -> Item` for moving forward and then create a rake task to update your database:

1. For all items where item.order == nil # legacy record
2. Create a new Order
3. Set new order.user_id to item.user_id and save
4. Set item.order_id to the new order.id and save
5. Rinse and repeat

Now your schema is set up correctly and all your legacy data has been migrated to the new format.  And best of all you're not stuck with trying to comply with the legacy format.

Sorry for the pseudocode but I'm sick today. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The only problem, is I wasn't speaking about legacy data where an Item does not have an Order.  Basically, a user creates various items.  All of these items go into their shopping cart.  At this point in time, there is no Order created for these items.  Then, once a user actually purchases a group of items, that's when the order is created.  So we can not set things up like: User -> Order -> Item, as there isn't necessary going to be an Order in the mix.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. :) I still think you should only use one workflow.  Say add a flag to the Order to determine its state and use it for the shopping cart.  When the user places the order change the state to an order.

Comment: @RichardBrown is correct. When a user first creates an item, you should create the corresponding order at the same time. You can then run a rake task (say every week) to delete incomplete orders.

Comment: I guess I could do that, but even with that implementation - at the time the Items are created, they are independent of each other.  Once an order is placed, the user gets to select which items go into their order.   So do you think I should initially create a new order for each item?  And then once the user actually places their order (by selecting many items to go into one order), associate all of those items to one order (lets just say the order associated with the 1st item), and just delete all orders associated with the rest of the items?